# Pressure Sensor Calibration

Tags: sensor, ethernet, spartan-6

[image][image]Here's the situation: I need to verify the pressure sensor accuracy of a control board. I have a software to verify the pressure and I am using Ethernet Communication to communicate between my control board and the laptop. I have to place the control board in the calibration jar. The calibration jar has 7-pin connectors on either end at its opening to connect the laptop and the board.  My concern is how do I connect the Ethernet port out (four wires)?
I am just out of school and this is one of my tasks at my workplace. Please help me!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for people to help you.  For instance: is this air pressure or hydraulic pressure?  What are the specific interfaces?  "7-pin" connector could be anything.

Comment: Is this an EE question or are you wishing to know how ethernet wires are connected to your network?

Comment: I want to measure the air pressure using the sensor located in the control board. I just attached the schematic and the pic of the board. The board is connected to a small battery to power up. As you can see in the schematic, the thick border line is that of the jar. The front end of the HR510-ND circular connector is connected to HR505-ND of the jar. The back end of the HR510-ND connects to the ethernet port of the board. So my question is how to connect the ethernet port out to the back end of HR510-ND using four wires? Should I just be using four metalic conductors and solder it to the end?

Comment: Hi and welcome... It isn't clear where there is any Ethernet on your circuit diagram, it looks there are only serial ports. If your problem is how to squeeze ethernet through only 4 wires (through the airtight connector), then this can probably be done. Please clarify first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can solder to the connector just get an Ethernet patch cable, cut it in half and then solder orange and green pairs to both sides of the connector. You don't need to worry about blue and brown pairs.

Before modding ask more senior colleagues at your workplace if it's OK to do this, just in case :-).

Comment: I just confirmed that I could solder the wires to the connector. Thanks! Will be implementing it this afternoon. :)